# Code Clean up - Several JQuery Popups

Tags: jquery, dry, code-cleanup

I'm using a repeating module for a client to have a popup on each product elemnt on their page. The code I have works, but I imagine it is very bloated and there could be a way to write it more concisely. Any help to find a cleaner way to write this would really help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.popbtn1").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).simplePopup({ type: "html", htmlSelector: "#poppost1" });
    });
    $("a.popbtn2").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).simplePopup({ type: "html", htmlSelector: "#poppost2" });
    });
    $("a.popbtn3").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).simplePopup({ type: "html", htmlSelector: "#poppost3" });
    });
    $("a.popbtn4").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).simplePopup({ type: "html", htmlSelector: "#poppost4" });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[class^=popbtn]").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var theClass = $(this).attr("class").match(/popbtn[\w-]*\b/).toString().replace("popbtn", "");
    console.log(theClass)
    $(this).simplePopup({
      type: "html",
      htmlSelector: "#poppost" + theClass
    });
  });

});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[class^=popbtn]").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var theClass = $(this).attr("class").match(/popbtn[\w-]*\b/).toString().replace("popbtn", "");
    console.log(theClass)
    $(this).simplePopup({
      type: "html",
      htmlSelector: "#poppost" + theClass
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="popbtn1">test</a>
```

Comment: hmm for some reason it does not seem to be working. I'm not even getting a console log popup for "theClass."